# K8S Jenkins Docker-in-Docker mount volume issue

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes

I am running a Jenkins deployment in my K8S cluster, and the mount looks like following.

```
          volumeMounts:
            - name: jenkins-home
              mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
            - name: docker-host-socket
              mountPath: "/var/run/docker.sock"
      volumes:
        - name: jenkins-home
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: jenkins-hostpath-pvc
        - name: docker-host-socket
          hostPath:
            path: /var/run/docker.sock
```

NOTE, the absolute path of the local storage on HOST is: `/var/openebs/local/pvc-17af5382-33cf-431f-b077-9bc136fef2db`

Any my Jenkinsfile is looks like.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
    docker {
        image 'ubuntu:20.04'
        args '--rm -t -u root -v /var/openebs/local/pvc-17af5382-33cf-431f-b077-9bc136fef2db:/var/jenkins_home -w /var/jenkins_home'
    }
}
    stages {
        stage('Load Container') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "Hello"'
                sh 'python3 --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above setup yield error that the

```
19:15:33  sh: 1: cannot create /var/jenkins_home/workspace/dataService_cicd@tmp/durable-4c009aeb/jenkins-log.txt: Directory nonexistent
19:15:33  sh: 1: cannot create /var/jenkins_home/workspace/dataService_cicd@tmp/durable-4c009aeb/jenkins-result.txt.tmp: Directory nonexistent
19:15:33  mv: cannot stat '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/dataService_cicd@tmp/durable-4c009aeb/jenkins-result.txt.tmp': No such file or directory
```

I decided to change the Jenkinsfile that I manually run Docker and mount the volume as follow.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Test Storage') {
            steps {
        sh 'docker run --rm -i --name jenkins_container -v /var/openebs/local/pvc-17af5382-33cf-431f-b077-9bc136fef2db:/var/jenkins_home -w /var/jenkins_home ubuntu:20.04'
        sh 'ls -la /var/jenkins_home'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it works as expected. May you please help me to use the Docker agent and mount the volume from HOST to insider container? Thanks.

Additionally, why does Jenkins mount another volume according to the output log.

```
$ docker run -t -d -u 0:0 --rm -i -e --privileged=true -v /var/openebs/local/pvc-17af5382-33cf-431f-b077-9bc136fef2db:/var/jenkins_home -w /var/jenkins_home -w /var/jenkins_home/workspace/dataService_cicd -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/dataService_cicd:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/dataService_cicd:rw,z -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/dataService_cicd@tmp:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/dataService_cicd@tmp:rw,z
```

Comment: Kubernetes clusters aren't guaranteed to be running Docker or to have an accessible Docker socket.  A Kubernetes pod also isn't usually guaranteed to run on any specific node, and using host directories for storage is not reliable on Kubernetes (you are likely to misplace data if a pod gets rescheduled, or actually lose it if a node is terminated and replaced).

Comment: Thank @DavidMaze , reserved a node only for scheduling Jenkins by specifying the nodeSelector. According to the console output, I found that the `docker run` command mounts twice. Firstly, it mount `-v /var/openebs/local/pvc-17af5382-33cf-431f-b077-9bc136fef2db:/var/jenkins_home -w /var/jenkins_home`. This is correct (Which I put in the args). But secondly, it mounds `-v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/dataService_cicd:/var/jenkins_home/workspace/dataService_cicd`. The second is wrong. I dont know how to completely override these args :(

Comment: Hi @ThaiLB, any progress?

Comment: I found similar issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/issues/626). It seems like it is specific to some Jenkins versions. Could you please share your versions of Jenkins, Docker, Docker plugin and Kubernetes?